# How to display dynamic ImageView from URL in infoWindow

Tags: android, infowindow

I'm trying to download an image and show it as an **ImageView** in my **infoWindow** , working with InfoWindowsAdapter , i put all the necessary code in the getInfoContents() method, but i can't get the image , in fact i can get it but still can't show it . 
As i read in the documentation,i have to recall the treatment to set the downloaded image , i have to use **showInfoWindow()** method because it's the only way to do it . I tried to use it in **getInfoContents()** just before the return  but , it blocks my app , need help !

This is my **getInfoContents()** :

```
  public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
  // set the view
  View v = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window,null);

  //assign values to the view field

   ImageView imagePlace =(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
   TextView tvLocality = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_place);

  //setting values with the parameter


  Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url_image_place).into(imagePlace);
  tvLocality.setText(marker.getTitle());

 //marker.showInfoWindow();
 return v;


}
```

This my **downloadIcon()** :

```
 private Bitmap downloadIcon(String iconURL) {
    Bitmap bmImg = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(iconURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        bmImg = null;
    }

    return bmImg;
}
```

**EDIT :** 
I used picasso to download my image , but the image is shown only after the second click , and any marker's infowindow that use the same image get the image in the first time , it means that the image have to be downloaded first !! i edited my **getInfoContents()** and i'm not using **downloadIcon()** anymore !

Comment: Does your code run in a thread? You can only download from internet if the code runs in a thread or asynctask. Assigning the bitmap to an imageview should be done on the main gui thread. I thing you have a 'speaking' logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), this is extremely easy. Simply write:

```
String url = ...;//Your url
ImageView imageView; //Your ImageView
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Or, If you want to do it yourself, you can implement an `AsyncTask`:

Definition:

```
private class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... param) {
            return downloadIcon(param[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            //Handle your result, i.e. your bitmap 
        }
}
```

Execution:

```
new ImageDownloader().execute(iconURL);
```

Comment: i read about this library , but i want to use showInfoWindow() , it's made to do what i need , but how to use it ?? for picasso i will use it but as last solution , thanks anyway :)

Comment: I highly recommend Picasso, I use it in all my projects which involves images. If you want to code it yourself, you need to start in the end which is hinted in the comments and other answers, and that's to put the networking call in a separate thread. @IsmailiAlaouismail

Comment: can u be more explicit please ?

Comment: trying to work with picasso , as u advise me , when i set this as context doesn't work :context cannot be applied to infowindowadapter !! u have any idea about that ?

Comment: Try `getContext();`/`getApplicationContext();`/`getActivity();` any of those. @IsmailiAlaouismail

Comment: i used getApplicationContext(); it works :D im glad !! thanks a lot marcus but u know why that the image works only after i click on the marker for the second time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940873/how-to-get-image-in-infowindow-in-the-first-click-on-marker , i really need ur help marcus

Answer (score 0):

You should not dowmload image by using main UI thread, so you need another thread to do it, something like:

```
public void setImage(final ImageView img, final String iconURL)
{

  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run()
     {
        Bitmap bmImg;               

        try {

              URL url = new URL(iconURL);
              HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              conn.setDoInput(true);
              conn.connect();
              InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
              bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             bmImg = null;
        }


        //after downloading, then talk to main ui
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {                      
              @Override
              public void run() 
              {
                   img.setImageBitmap(bmImg);

              } 
        }


     }}).start();

 }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: i put this code at the beginning of getInfoContents , but bmImg must be final so it's impossible because i need to rewrite it

Comment: You should not call above codes inside getInfoContents, I just update answer with more

Comment: but my url is unknown outside getInfoContents !! as i said in my question , i get the url from the marker object ( parameter of getInfoContents)

Comment: Ok I see, for your case I suggest to use some [ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library, which can load image asynchronously

Comment: @IsmailiAlaouismail I just made a `setImage(...)` method, you can call it inside `getInfoContent`, I have not tested it, hope it work